# cakephp accessing view attributes/variables from within a helper

Tags: php, cakephp, view, helper

is there a reasonable way to access the view attribute "passedArgs" (or any similar)

```
/* view */
$this->passedArgs
```

from within a Helper?

I'd be happy to customize the _construct() of the helper or to customize the app_helper... but I don't want to have to pass `$this->passedArgs` into the helper on every view or usage.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Cake 2.x and 3.x**

You can look up your variables in the `_View` object:

```
$this->_View->viewVars['foo'];
```

**Cake 1.x**

If you grab the current view object from within the helper you should be able to get to its passedArgs.

```
class SomeHelper extends AppHelper {
  function __construct($settings = array()){
    $this->passedArgs = ClassRegistry::getObject('view')->passedArgs;
  }
}
```

**Cake 1.2.x**

If you grab the current view object from within the helper you should be able to get to its viewVars.

```
class SomeHelper extends AppHelper {
  function __construct($settings = array()){
    $this->viewVars = ClassRegistry::getObject('view')->viewVars;
  }
}
```

Enjoy,
Nick

Comment: For me I needed to get the view variables set from the controller, so it was:

`$this->viewVars = ClassRegistry::getObject('view')->viewVars;`

This is then an array, the keys of which being the name of the variables which are extracted and used in the view during render.

Comment: In CakePHP 2.x, you can access the viewVars from a helper's method using: `$this->_View->viewVars['var']`

Comment: +1 for atomicguava, that works whereas ClassRegistry doesn't for me.  (Cake 2.3 stable)

Comment: I opted to put this on the AppHelper::__construct() to make it available for all our helpers.

Answer (score 2):

Cake 3:

```
$this->getView()->get('my_var');
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just setting the view's value from the AppController?

```
class AppController extends Controller {
 function beforeFilter() {
  // other stuff
  $this->set( 'passed_args', $this->params['pass'] );
 }
}
```