# Add input field into all forms - cakephp

Tags: forms, cakephp

I need to add a hidden input field into each form in all pages of the website with some value(defined in the controller), to be submitted with the form.

I can not do it by JS, as I am using security component and it will give a "black-holed" error(and I do not want to prevent that, I mean adding that field into unlocked Fields list).  Is there some way of doing so ?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use a custom helper which will generate hidden field in side the form and assign value to do this.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just be able to add it in your view? `$this->Form->input('field', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $something))`;

Comment: I can, but imagine if you have dozens of forms or more.. just need a fast solution

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `FormHelper` and add the hidden input when creating the form:

```
App::import('Helper', 'Form') ;

class MyFormHelper extends FormHelper {

    public function create ($model = null, $options = array()) {
        return parent::create($model, $options).$this->_myInput() ;
    }

    protected function _myInput () {
        return parent::input('myfield', array(
            'value' => $this->_View->viewVars['myVarName'] ;
        ));
    }

}
```

This code only works with CakePHP 2.x, for previous version see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525541/cakephp-accessing-view-attributes-variables-from-within-a-helper) to get a way to access view variables in a helper.

Then in your `AppController`, just add:

```
public $helpers = array(
    'Form' => array(
        'className' => 'MyForm'
    )
) ;
```

Comment: Why private? Should be protected and you're not following the CakePHP conventions, protected should be prefixed with _ and private with __.

Comment: @burzum Why protected instead of private? The conventions you're talking about are useful for plugins or libraries, I'm giving a simple example for something the OP won't probably distribute in a plugin/library, and if he does he will certainly modify my code.

Comment: @Holt tks for the answer, I will give it a try and get back, I think should work definitely.

Comment: @Holt I completely disagree, conventions are *always* important. Private should be only use on methods that are completely critical and indicate "You're not supposed to access this for a good reason." Code should be always extendible, like you said people can change the code any way but then they'll have to change the visibility scope or modify internals (very likely a API breaking change) instead of being just able to extend a the class. The whole CakePHP framework hasn't a single private method for that reason.

Comment: @burzum I agree with you about the `protected` visibility, my code was wrong. And I did not say conventions were not important, only that you don't have to follow CakePHP coding conventions because you're using it in your own application (I am not talking about CakePHP conventions that make code easier such as default naming, etc.).